# Haskell type error "Couldn't match type `Char' with `t0 [Char]'"

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a dnaChecker funtion and get this error. I don't know what is wrong. If someone could explain the error or give me some tips that would be great!
Here is the error and the code:

> ```
>   * Couldn't match type `Char' with `t0 [Char]'
>   Expected type: [t0 [Char]]
>     Actual type: String
> * In the second argument of `all', namely `sekvens'
>   In the expression: all (elem "ACGT") sekvens
>   In a stmt of a pattern guard for
>                  an equation for `dnaChecker':
>     all (elem "ACGT") sekvens
> ```

```
dnaChecker :: String -> SekvensTyp  
dnaChecker sekvens
                | all (elem "ACGT") sekvens = Dna
                | all (elem "ARNDCEQGHILKMFPSTWYV") sekvens = Protein
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`elem "ACGT"` is a function that checks if the string `"ACGT"` is an element of its argument. What you want is

```
(`elem` "ACGT")
```

, which is a function that checks if its argument is an element of `"ACGT"`.

```
dnaChecker :: String -> SekvensTyp  
dnaChecker sekvens
            | all (`elem` "ACGT") sekvens = Dna
            | all (`elem` "ARNDCEQGHILKMFPSTWYV") sekvens = Protein
```

Treating `elem` as an infix function lets us write a succinct section, rather than writing out an explicit lambda expression like `\x -> elem x "ACGT"`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still get an error:   * Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `t0 a0 -> Bool'  * In the expression: all . map (elem "ACGT") $ sekvens
      In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                     an equation for `dnaChecker':
        all . map (elem "ACGT") $ sekvens
      In an equation for `dnaChecker':
          dnaChecker sekvens
            | all . map (elem "ACGT") $ sekvens = Dna
            | all . map (elem "ARNDCEQGHILKMFPSTWYV") $ sekvens = Protein

Comment: Oh, the wrong function is being mapped. See the update.

Comment: Actually, the whole thing is not yet right. I (or *someone*) will post an actual correction shortly.

Comment: Could you please explain why the `elem` makes it work? I dont understand the logic, like what is going on? `elem` is an infix function but doesnt have anything to the left

Comment: by argument do you mean sekvens?

Comment: Well, each character of `sekvens`. `all` behaves something like `map`: it applies its first argument to each element of its second argument, but instead of returning a list, it returns a `Bool` indicating if each function call produced a true value. (My original answer was wrong because I forgot that `all` doesn't simply take a list of boolean values and reduces it to a single value.)

Comment: ahaaaaaaaa!!!! That makes sense :) many thanks, that was the explanation I was looking for!